# Djnago model instance only update after calling objects.get() again (DRF Test case)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an APIView (**DRF**), where I set the user is_active field to False instead of deleting him, everything works as expected, but I have a wired behavior when I try to make a test case for the view, I try to test if the field 'is_active' is False after calling the ApiView but it remains 'True' if change the code a little bit and call user.objects.get() with the same user email after calling the ApiView, the new instance field is_active is False.

I've never encountered this behavior, can someone explain the reason behind it? thanks!

this test passes:

```
def test_delete_account(self):
        self.authentication() # create user and log him in
        user = User.objects.get(email=self.sample_user['email'])
        self.assertEqual(user.is_active, True)
        response = self.client.post(reverse('delete-account'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        user = User.objects.get(email=self.sample_user['email']) 
        self.assertEqual(user.is_active,False)
```

this test fails:

```
def test_delete_account(self):
        self.authentication() # create user and log him in
        user = User.objects.get(email=self.sample_user['email'])
        self.assertEqual(user.is_active, True)
        response = self.client.post(reverse('delete-account'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        self.assertEqual(user.is_active,False) # FAILS HERE
```

delete account ApiView:

```
class DeleteAccountAPIView(GenericAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        user = self.request.user
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        return  Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, you are calling a 'remote' request, the changes are in 'remote':

```
     client ---- (call via post) --> remote 
   (the test)                   (django web app)
       |                               |
       ---------------------------------
                     |
                 database
```

This is what it happens:

```
# you get a user from database
user = User.objects.get(email=self.sample_user['email'])

# you make a post to 'remote' server
response = self.client.post(reverse('delete-account'))

# no changes should be in 'client' side
self.assertEqual(user.is_active,True)

# when you refresh data from database
user = User.objects.get(email=self.sample_user['email']) 

# you get the current database data that contains changes from remote
self.assertEqual(user.is_active,False)
```